# How to create multiple sockets as an index

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have a VB application where winsock is used. I want to convert it to VB.Net, so as I understand I should use System.net.sockets to do this.

But the problem is in the VB application multiple sockets are created by using the index feature of the winsock . example

Load Socket(isocket)

where isocket is an integer variable that is incremented each time, for a new connection request.

So how do I do the same, ie. open multiple sockets in vb.net?

Comment: Create a new instance of the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class? Use the `New` keyword to invoke the constructor method.

Comment: yes create instances, but I want it indexed. So that I can call/refer it by the index value....

Comment: So place those instances into an array, the same way you'd do it in VB 6. Only difference is that *all* arrays are zero-indexed in .NET, no matter what.

Comment: could you give an example of how exactly to do this. Bcos in vb the control winsock itself has index..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB6 the Winsock is an OCX so what you are doing by calling `Load Socket(Index)` is creating a new instance of the ActiveX Control. There is no such equivalent in VB.NET so what you *could* do is create a collection of System.Net.Sockets.Socket:

```
Dim collSockets As New Collection(Of System.Net.Sockets.Socket)
```

When you get a new connection request, create a new item in the collection:

```
 Dim sck As New System.Net.Sockets.Socket(**Initialise Your New Socket Here**)
 collSockets.Add(sck)
```

Then you can access your sockets by Index (zero based):

```
collSockets(0).Whatever()
```

Comment: Thanks, great idea.. But I tried the code.. Could you let me know why I am getting this error message - Error 1 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments

Comment: @user733957 Yes you need to use this `Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel` at the top of your class

Answer (score 0):

Then we can do something like this:

```
dim x as integer = 0
x += 1
collSockets(x).Whatever()
```

That will make new socket in each event and the x will double will be like

```
collSocket(1).Whatever()
x+= 1
collSocket(2).Whatever()
```

Etc.

Comment: Please put some effort into your answers. Even after fixing the formatting and orthography this is barely comprehensible.